# Switch cursor focus to first text box in HTML in FF24

Tags: firefox

When I open a new tab in FF24, the cursor focus goes to the address bar, which is very annoying because my home page is Google and, by habit, I start typing stuff thinking it goes in the search box.  Is there any way (`about:config`) to switch the focus by default from the address bar into the first text box in HTML (which, in the above example, would be the Google search box)?

Answer (score 0):

No, not by default, at least not by using any of the hundred or so extensions that I looked at in the Search category - there are about a thousand others.

However, whatever you type in the address bar, if it's not a web location, gets searched in your currently selected search engine. You can press `Ctrl+K` (or on Mac, `Cmd+K`) to move the focus to the browser window's search box, where Alt (or Option) and the up/down arrow keys permit you to select a search engine.

If you switch to Chrome, you can press Tab to move the focus to the page's search box.